# Draw and edit rectangle and circle shapes in mapbox

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

In my job we are about to transition from **gmaps** to **mapbox** but I haven't found a way to draw and edit circles or rectangles with the mouse.

Comment: This is the Mapbox drawing library for GL maps https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw

Comment: I have checked the library but not found a way to for example show handlers to edit the size of a rectangle area, or create that with mouse events

Comment: Does this example help? https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-draw/

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the js api with Leaflet, I have seen that example you mention but did not help to much.

Comment: Ah ok, I just updated the question's tags to reflect that!